# How to reshape data to long format by combining multiple columns and repeating rows?

Tags: r

I have the below example data and I'm aiming to convert it to long format.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  
  subject = rep(paste("subject", 1:10), each = 4),
  prac1 = round(rnorm(40, 0.25, 0.03), 3),
  prac2 = round(rnorm(40, 0.25, 0.03), 3),
  prac3 = round(rnorm(40, 0.25, 0.03), 3),
  prac1_vs_crit1 = round(rnorm(40, 0.01, 0.005), 3),
  prac2_vs_crit1 = round(rnorm(40, 0.01, 0.005), 3),
  prac3_vs_crit1 = round(rnorm(40, 0.01, 0.005), 3),
  prac1_vs_crit2 = round(rnorm(40, 0.01, 0.005), 3),
  prac2_vs_crit2 = round(rnorm(40, 0.01, 0.005), 3),
  prac3_vs_crit2 = round(rnorm(40, 0.01, 0.005), 3)
  
)
```

Columns 2-4 are practical estimates and 5-10 are differences between the practical (`prac1`, `prac2`, `prac3`) and two different criterions (`crit1`/`crit2`). Each subject has four rows to represent four different trials.

```
    subject prac1 prac2 prac3 prac1_vs_crit1 prac2_vs_crit1 prac3_vs_crit1
1 subject 1 0.261 0.245 0.257          0.011          0.008          0.008
2 subject 1 0.196 0.277 0.269          0.012          0.002          0.019
3 subject 1 0.235 0.249 0.189          0.010          0.006          0.010
4 subject 1 0.217 0.186 0.261          0.007          0.003          0.015
5 subject 2 0.269 0.225 0.218          0.013          0.009          0.017
6 subject 2 0.254 0.245 0.304          0.016          0.008          0.006
  prac1_vs_crit2 prac2_vs_crit2 prac3_vs_crit2
1          0.013          0.008          0.016
2          0.008          0.010          0.007
3          0.002          0.008          0.006
4          0.005          0.012          0.013
5          0.009          0.011          0.003
6          0.011          0.012          0.026
```

I'd like to transform my data to long format so it looks like this:

```
    subject     comparison difference prac_value
1 subject 1 prac1_vs_crit1      0.011      0.261
2 subject 1 prac2_vs_crit1      0.008      0.245
3 subject 1 prac3_vs_crit1      0.008      0.257
4 subject 1 prac1_vs_crit2      0.013      0.261
5 subject 1 prac2_vs_crit2      0.008      0.245
6 subject 1 prac3_vs_crit2      0.016      0.257
```

Where each subject has 24 rows (6 rows per trial) with `prac_value` representing the value that coincides with the column named after the first separator ("_") in the original format. For example, for `subject 1` and `prac1_vs_crit1`, the `prac_value` should be 0.261 as `prac1` in the original format had this value.

Where I'm stuck is how to approach this problem, specifically as it relates to achieving the desired output for the `prac_value` column. Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by first renaming your columns in a consistent manner and two `pivot_longer`s like so:

```r
set.seed(123)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dat_long <- dat |> 
  rename_with(.fn = ~ paste0(.x, "_value"), matches("^prac\\d+$")) |> 
  rename_with(.fn = ~ gsub("_vs", "", .x)) |> 
  pivot_longer(-subject, names_to = c("prac", ".value"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  pivot_longer(c(crit1, crit2), names_to = "crit", values_to = "difference") |> 
  unite(comparison, prac, crit, sep = "_vs_") |> 
  rename(prac_value = value)

head(dat_long)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   subject   comparison     prac_value difference
#>   <chr>     <chr>               <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 subject 1 prac1_vs_crit1      0.233      0.011
#> 2 subject 1 prac1_vs_crit2      0.233      0.006
#> 3 subject 1 prac2_vs_crit1      0.229      0.015
#> 4 subject 1 prac2_vs_crit2      0.229      0.002
#> 5 subject 1 prac3_vs_crit1      0.25       0.021
#> 6 subject 1 prac3_vs_crit2      0.25       0.011

count(dat_long, subject)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    subject        n
#>    <chr>      <int>
#>  1 subject 1     24
#>  2 subject 10    24
#>  3 subject 2     24
#>  4 subject 3     24
#>  5 subject 4     24
#>  6 subject 5     24
#>  7 subject 6     24
#>  8 subject 7     24
#>  9 subject 8     24
#> 10 subject 9     24
```